# Old file gets downloaded from web in some ISPs

Tags: webserver, isp

I have a web server in which I used to keep files for my customers. I have a txt file named update.txt and I used to refer that for update purpose.
I was getting complaint from some of my clients that they are not getting updates at right time.

Recently I have noticed a problem while reading that update.txt, I have replaced the txt with new one but when read that via browser it was still showing old txt.

I have cleared the browsing history, cache also reset the Internet explorer but the problem was still there. Even I deleted file from web server but still I am getting old file. 
After 2-3 days the problem gets solved automatically, but I can’t make my clients to wait 2-3 days.

So I changed the internet to another ISP then problem solved. So I think some Internet service providers are keeping the cache of web for the speed purpose.

If my guess is correct then how can I avoid the cache of my files by Internet service providers?

If my guess is wrong what might be the other reasons for this?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set up proper cache headers to tell the client and the possible proxies not to cache it.  Changing ISP for that is certainly not a solution as it won't solve the problem for your clients.

This can not be handled in the text file alone.  Applications normally use server-side scripts that could easily accommodate such requirements by sending the appropriate HTTP headers.